# Django's query set filter with icontains stops working if there isn't at least one regisrty with unempty data at target column, what's the logic?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-q

Okay, so I made a search form with some select fields I use to filter what plant species will appear in the search result page, like only species of a specific family.

**How it works:** no value selected on any of the fileds, it returns all species. If you select something, it will filter species with that property or properties.

So far it was working because I only filtered mandatory fields like family that all the species were required to have, **the moment I added a query related to a field with no information on any of the species it made all searches return nothing**, even without selecting any of the filters.

[image]

So just to see if it would change anything, **I inserted the information on the new fields using Django admin, and it started working as intended** (meaning the filter was working and selecting nothing was showing all species again).

**Here is my query set logic that works as long as there is a single species with data in searched columns:**

```
exemplares = Exemplar.objects.all()

q = Q(tipoDeExemplar__opção__icontains=tipoDeExemplar) & \
    Q(especie__familia__opção__icontains=familia) & \
    Q(especie__genero__opcao__icontains=genero) & \
    Q(especie__epiteto__opcao__icontains=epiteto) & \
    Q(especie__variedade__opção__icontains=variedade) & \
    Q(especie__grupoVegetal__opcao__icontains=grupoVegetal) & \
    Q(especie__familiaLegada__opção__icontains=familiaLegada) & \
    Q(especie__generoLegado__opcao__icontains=generoLegado) & \
    Q(especie__epitetoLegado__opcao__icontains=epitetoLegado)

exemplares = exemplares.filter(q)

return exemplares
```

When the field on the front-end is empty, it's value is an empty string:

```
<option value="" selected></option>
```

This is one of the fields' model:

```
familiaLegada = models.ForeignKey(Familia, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Família Legada", related_name='familiaLegada')
```

I don't get why it works as long as there is one species with something in the fields I used to make the query, I wonder if there is something to do with null on the database, what could be the problem?